# JSF 2.x hide messages layer when empty

Tags: css, jsf-2, icefaces

Is there a way the  output layer (? if that is the correct term) could be hidden when it is empty such that when info/error messages are written to it, it expands to the height required to fit the messages, vertically stretching the panel that it is contained within? (perhaps using CSS ??)

```
<h:body>  
  <ace:panel>
...
...
    <h:panelGroup>   
      <h:messages
        infoStyle="color:darkgreen"
        errorStyle="color:darkred">
      </h:messages> 
    </h:panelGroup>   
  </ace:panel>
</h:body>
```

Comment: The `<h:panel>` doesn't exist at all. Aren't you actually using PrimeFaces and incorrectly overgeneralizing as if it's standard JSF? Please do not do that. You should post actual code and not create red herrings. Coming back to your concrete question, do you mean that you want to hide the fictive `<h:panel>` when there are no messages?

Comment: Opps. Newbie typo. Wasn't looking to generalise. I am using some of the nice looking ICEFaces components. That's an <ace:panel> have corrected my post. Correct about your second question. With a test app I am making, for the time being some error messages are a bit verbose. What I have in mind is to have <h:panelGroup> hidden when there are no messages. When messages are written out, it can stretch (perhaps even introduce a scrollbar, if the message is very large). Or perhaps a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that **all** messages are handled by the one and same `<h:messages>`, you could just check if [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29) isn't empty.

```
<ace:panel rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}">
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. The beauty of a good solution lies in its simplicity! I used the rendered clause in the panelGroup that holds the messages.